# Django not taking timezone from Postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a postgres database with a local timezone (America/Bogota), so my timestamp column looks like this ***"2020-04-24 07:35:11.129-05"*** but when I call the data from Django it changes the timezone to 00 but keeps the same date-hour, (***2020-04-24T07:35:11.129000+00:00***) I'have tried changing the TIME_ZONE in the Django settings to America/Bogota but then I got no results, any ideas on how can a i fix this?

This is the settings.py

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

views.py

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.core.serializers import serialize

def data(request):
    time = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=8)
    hour = serialize('geojson',datatime.objects.filter(tiempo__gte=time)[0:100])
    return HttpResponse(hour, content_type='json')
```

Comment: 'America/Bogota' is a correct timezone definition string (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Keep it and issue a `python manage.py shell` inside your project and try to fiddle with test code there.